# When submitting form it enters multiple rows within mysql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

The below test code which has already been suggested by a helpful member is causing some unexpected issues. Firstly when I submit the "cust_submit" button it enters multiple entries into the database for some reason rather than just one line of input.

Secondly, I wanted to include an auto-increment ID of the "inf_submit" section but it throws the error "Only variables can be passed by reference in"

```
<?php
ob_start(); //Turns on output buffering
session_start(); //This starts a session variable where it store the input so the user doesnt have to start over if they get an error
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test-sql"); //connection variables
  
$timezone = date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
  
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

if ($con->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ". $con->connect_error);
    } echo "connected successfully";
?>

<html>
<head>
<!-- here we add the links and the jquery-->
<title>Register Project</title>
</head>
<body>
        
<div id="first">
    <form action="fromstackoverview.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Inf_fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Inf_lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="inf_submit" value="Register">
        
    </form>
</div>

<div id="second">
                
    <form action="fromstackoverview.php" method="POST">                 
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Cust_fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <br>                                             
    <input type="text" name="Cust_lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="cust_email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="cust_submit" value="Register">
                        
    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>

 <?php

 $inf_fname = "";
 $cust_fname = "";
 $inf_lname = "";
 $cust_lname = "";
 $cust_em = "";


 if(isset($_POST['inf_submit'])) {

     $inf_fname = strip_tags($_POST['Inf_fname']);
     $inf_fname = str_replace(' ', '', $inf_fname);
     $_SESSION['Inf_fname'] = $inf_fname;
     $inf_lname = strip_tags($_POST['Inf_lname']);
     $inf_lname = str_replace(' ', '', $inf_lname);
     $_SESSION['Inf_lname'] = $inf_lname;

     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO inf VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", '', $inf_fname, $inf_lname);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 } else if (isset($_POST['cust_submit'])) {

     $cust_fname = strip_tags($_POST['Cust_fname']);
     $cust_fname = str_replace(' ', '', $cust_fname);
     $_SESSION['Cust_fname'] = $cust_fname;
     $cust_lname = strip_tags($_POST['Cust_lname']);
     $cust_lname = str_replace(' ', '', $cust_lname);
     $_SESSION['Cust_lname'] = $cust_lname;
     $cust_em = strip_tags($_POST['cust_email']); //removes html tags
     $cust_em = str_replace(' ', '', $cust_em); //remove spaces in name
     $cust_em = ucfirst(strtolower($cust_em)); //This will keep the first letter upper case and lower case everything else
    $_SESSION['cust_email'] = $cust_em; //Stores input into session variable

     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO customer VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $cust_fname, $cust_lname, $cust_em);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: "i wanted to include a auto increment ID "...if a column is an auto-increment column, then you can't include it in your INSERT query. After all, it's not - logical what value are you going to pass to it? The database will generate the value for you - that's the whole point. if you try to include it in your query and pass any kind of value (even null or a blank string) you'll get a SQL error. (Your actual error is because you tried to pass a literal string to bind_param, but it only allows you to pass variables - because there's no point in binding a literal, it isn't vulnerable to manipulation

Comment: Anyway, the code you've shown isn't capable of inserting multiple lines simultaneously. Something else is going on (e.g. people double-clicking on the submit button perhaps, or re-posting the form by trying to refresh the browser), or simultaneous users creating records, or something like that. It isn't directly the fault of this code, it contains no loops or other mechanisms for repeating the insert. It must be that the PHP script is being called more than once somehow.

Comment: @ADyson I see, thanks. I uncommented it. I don't know why OP commented this code out.

Comment: Is this script named "fromstackoverflow.php"? Also, can you confirm if the submitted information comes from form 1 or form 2? Because there doesn't look to be any code here that would run a query twice. So if you put info into form 1 and hit submit and same with form 2, which one gives a double insert?

Comment: Hi all, so the section was commented out for inf_submit because it just throws an error in its current format. Understood thank you ADyson i have now added an empty variable which now no longer throws an error for "cust_submit" and enters the data as expected. With regards to the multiple submission thats odd because i was just using this snippet to test adding to sql so no one is using other than me, but when i add some php to not allow duplicates maybe that would stop it happening anyway.